# TinyXML and fetching values

Tags: c++, templates, tinyxml

I'm trying to load data from xml-file with TinyXML (c++).

```
int height = rootElem->attrib<int>("height", 480);
```

**rootElem** is a root element of loaded xml-file. I want to load **height** value from it (integer). But I have a wrapper function for this stuff:

```
template<typename T>
T getValue(const string &key, const string &defaultValue = "")
{
    return mRootElement->attrib<T>(key, defaultValue);
}
```

It works with string:

```
std::string temp = getValue<std::string>("width");
```

And it fails during fetching:

```
int temp = getValue<int>("width");


>no matching function for call to ‘TiXmlElement::attrib(const std::string&, const std::string&)’
```

**UPD**: The new version of code:

```
template<typename T>
T getValue(const string &key, const T &defaultValue = T())
{
    return mRootElement->attrib<T>(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are calling the int version of TiXmlElement::attrib, but you are giving it a defualtValue of type const std::string &, however, the function expects a defaultValue of type int.

Answer (score 1):

`attrib<T>(key, defaultValue)` probably expect it's first argument to be of same type as it's second template argument.

In other words; `T` in `mRootElement->attrib<T>(key, defaultValue)` must be of the same type as `defaultValue`.